# Time expiry dictionary in memory in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, caching, ttl

I was just wondering how one might efficiently implement a time expiry dictionary in memory in Python such that key-value pairs expire after a specified time interval.

Comment: Do you have a example of what a expiry hash table is? Have your implemented this in another language?

Comment: Nope...I was just wondering what a feasible logic might be

Comment: What happens when they "expire"?

Comment: You may want to check out [cachetools](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools) which has a TTL cache that seems to do what your describing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python in-memory cache with time to live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771286/python-in-memory-cache-with-time-to-live)

Answer (score 10):

The design pattern to typically do this is not via a dictionary, but via a function or method decorator. The dictionary is managed behind the scenes by the cache.

This answer uses the [`ttl_cache`](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cachetools.func.ttl_cache) decorator in [`cachetools==3.1.0`](https://pypi.org/project/cachetools) with Python 3.7. It works a lot like [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), but with a [time to live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live). As for its implementation logic, consider its [source code](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools).

```
import cachetools.func

@cachetools.func.ttl_cache(maxsize=128, ttl=10 * 60)
def example_function(key):
    return get_expensively_computed_value(key)


class ExampleClass:
    EXP = 2

    @classmethod
    @cachetools.func.ttl_cache()
    def example_classmethod(cls, i):
        return i**cls.EXP

    @staticmethod
    @cachetools.func.ttl_cache()
    def example_staticmethod(i):
        return i**3
```

---

If however you insist on using a dictionary, `cachetools` also has [`TTLCache`](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cachetools.TTLCache).

```
import cachetools

ttl_cache = cachetools.TTLCache(maxsize=128, ttl=10 * 60)
```

Comment: can it set the TTL to all keys together at once in the dict, instead of setting by one key. e.g.: all the content of ttl_cache disappear at once after TTL.