# Is there a way to implement a dictionary with expiring keys in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

I want to implement a dictionary with keys having a TTL (Time to live).
I have tried the **Passive Removal** of the keys approach, where the keys whose TTL have expired are removed on access (by set and get function). (same as this approach: https://pypi.org/project/expiringdict/)

Can we implement the functionality (in Python) of removing the expired keys in a periodic manner, where we use a **thread** that runs **periodically (say every 5 seconds)** to remove the expired keys?

Comment: Try this https://pypi.org/project/expiringdict/

Comment: @MubtadaNaqvi Thank you for the reference. I really appreciate it. I have read the approach discussed in the link you mentioned. I want to know if we can implement the periodic expiration of keys using threads in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time expiry dictionary in memory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244035/time-expiry-dictionary-in-memory-in-python)

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution for this problem?