# How long beam setup() refresh in python Dataflow DoFn life cycle?

Tags: streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a streaming pipeline where I need to query from BigQuery as reference for my pipeline transform. Since BigQuery tables are only changed in 2 weeks, I put the query cache in setup() instead of start_bundle(). From observing logs, I saw that start_bundle() will refresh its value in DoFn life cycle around 50-100 element process but setup() will never be refreshed. Is there any way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you did not provide you code I will answer your question based in your explanation.

**First**, regarding [DoFn.start_bundle()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn.start_bundle), this function is called for every bundle and it is up for DataFlow to decide the size of these, based on the metrics gathered during execution.

**Second**,[DoFn.setup()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn.setup) is called once per worker. It will be only called again if the worker is restarted. Moreover, as a comparison [DoFn.processElement()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn.process) is called once per element.

Since you need to refresh your query twice per week, it would be the perfect use for [SideInput](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/) using ["Slowly-changing lookup cache"](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-1). You can use this approach when you have a look up table which changes from time to time. So you need to update the result of the lookup. However, instead of using a single query in batch mode, you can use streaming mode. It allows you to update the result of the lookup (in your case the query's result) based on a GlobalWindow. Afterwards, having this side input you can use it within your main stream PCollection.

***Note:** I must point that as a limitation sideInputs won't work properly with huge amounts of data (many Gbs or Tb). Furthermore, [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985753/what-is-the-difference-between-dofn-setup-and-dofn-startbundle/50068377#50068377) is very informative.*

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is good. As an alternative, you could invoke a method in `start_bundle()` returns a cached version of the results as long as it's fresh enough and does a full read from BQ otherwise. See, e.g. [Python in-memory cache with time to live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771286/python-in-memory-cache-with-time-to-live)